# Spherical Coordinate Mapping creating double epsilons

Tags: c++, graphics, imagemagick

Here is an image: [http://i.imgur.com/MRvz24u.gif](https://i.imgur.com/MRvz24u.gif)

So I can tell what the problem is, that my epsilon (or whatever that symbol is) used for spherical coordinates are repeating. So the way I calculate the points is:

```
double theta = acos(p.getY()/p.magnitude());
theta = theta/3.1415926;

double epsilon = atan(p.getZ()/p.getX());
epsilon = epsilon + 3.1415926/2;
epsilon = epsilon /3.1415926;
```

I'm pretty sure the rest isn't the problem but I will put it here just in case

```
    int w = texture ->columns();
    int h = texture ->rows();

    double x = w * epsilon ; x = (int) x;
    double y = h * theta; y = (int) y;

    int row = y;
    int column = x;

    Magick::PixelPacket *pixels = texture->getPixels(0, 0, w, h);
    Magick::Color color = pixels[w * row + column];

    double range = pow(2, texture -> modulusDepth());

    double r = color.redQuantum()/range ;
    double g = color.greenQuantum()/range ;
    double b = color.blueQuantum()/range ;

    return Color(r, g, b, 0);
```

I am not sure why I would be getting repeating values because my range should originally be -pi/2 < epsilon < pi/2 and I just shift it then scale it.

Comment: Try using `atan2`, it accepts x and y instead of x/y and handles signs better.

Comment: I just switched it. generating a new gif. Don't think it worked though :(

Comment: link : http://i.imgur.com/eNyoRm9.gif

Comment: Wait, this has a different range. After I changed it, I believe it works

Comment: I'll turn this into an answer, then.

Answer (score 1):

Use `atan2` instead of `atan`. `atan` accepts x/y while `atan2` accepts x,y .

This allows `atan2` handle the case where x and y are both negative differently from the case where they're positive. `atan` has no way of knowing.